# Pull a un branch remoto que no existe en mi local

Tags: git

Un compañero de trabajo creó un `branch` llamado `feature/validateEmail`. Quiero hacer `pull` o `checkout` de ese `branch`en mi máquina para poder trabajar en él pero sin esperar a que haga `merge` a `develop` o a `master`.

He intentado sin éxito:

- `git checkout feature/validateEmail`
- `git checkout validateEmail`
- `git pull feature/validateEmail`
- `git pull validateEmail`

Y como uso el [plugin](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/tree/master/plugins/git) de `oh my zsh` también intenté:

- `gco feature/validateEmail`
- `gco validateEmail`

El `branch` lo puedo ver con:

- `gba` (por el plugin)
- `git branch -a`

¿Cómo puedo hacer pull o checkout de el repositorio remoto en mi máquina?

Comment: Los branch no se clonan, los que se clonan son los repos

Comment: @CarlosMuñoz Gracias, ya edité la pregunta, no supe cómo traducir `pull`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Primero debes hacer un fetch

```
git fetch <remoto> <rama>
```

Fetch trae la rama remota, en el caso tuyo la de tu compañero y la almacena dentro de `<remoto>/<rama>`

Pull es una combinación de fetch+merge
Cuando hagas el `fetch` puedes hacer `checkout` a esa rama dentro del remoto sin mezclarla con alguna local y luego, hacer `merge`.
Otra opción rápida también sería crear una rama localmente, hacer `checkout` a esa rama y luego hacer pull de la rama remota.

El problema con `pull` como lo expresas en tu pregunta, es que hace tanto el fetch como un `merge` automático de esa rama a la rama donde está situado actualmente.

Para tu caso puntual harías:

```
git fetch feature validateEmail
```

Luego entras a esa rama remota con:

```
git checkout feature/validateEmail
```

Y realizas los cambios que necesites para luego hacer `merge` con master o con cualquier otra rama.

Answer (score 8):

Tendrias que hacer un fetch primero

```
git fetch <remote> <branchremoto>:<branchlocal> 
git checkout <branchlocal>
```

Si tu remote es origin:

```
git fetch origin feature/validateEmail:validateEmail
git checkout validateEmail
```

Documentación de [git-fetch](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch)

Si lo que quieres hacer es en un clone del repositorio, tendrías que agregar el repositorio como remote:

```
git remote add companiero https://github.com/user/repo.git
```