# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre pull y fetch en git?

Tags: git, git-push

¿Cuáles son específicamente las diferencias entre hacer un `git pull` y un `git fetch`?

Comment: Aquí respondí sobre esa misma pregunta. http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/191/pull-a-un-branch-remoto-que-no-existe-en-mi-local

Answer (score 60, accepted):

De la [documentación](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull):

> `git pull` is shorthand for `git fetch` followed by `git merge FETCH_HEAD`.

o haciendo una traducción libre:

> `git pull` es una abreviación de `git fetch` seguido de `git merge FETCH_HEAD`.

Es decir, `git fetch` trae los cambios, pero los deja en otro ***branch***, hasta que se hace el `git merge` para traerlos al ***branch*** local.

Comment: osea que el fetch solo baja los cambios sin hacerles merge localmente?

Comment: @jpganz18, correcto.

Comment: supongo que los dejara en el mismo branch solo para darles git add, no?

Comment: 'Que los deja en otro branch' ¿en cuál?

Comment: Los deja en un branch oculto llamado `origin/master`, si quieren ver las ramas ocultas usen: `git branch -a`, lo explico mejor en la respuesta que te deje. - @dwarandae

Comment: Es tremendamente confuso que pongas "master" cuando no estamos hablando de una rama master en concreto. Origin/XXXX siendo XXXX el nombre de la rama de la que estás haciendo fetch. Pero no descarga nada de la red, simplemente actualiza los punteros de información.

Answer (score 60):

Siempre en un repositorio tienes una rama oculta, que puedes ver al usar `git branch -a`.

Esa rama oculta es `origin/master`.

Tú al usar `git fetch`, bajas los cambios del **repositorio remoto** a la rama `origin/master`:

> git fetch origin

Ahora ya tienes los cambios en `origin/master`, pero tendrías que pasarlos a la rama `master`, para eso tienes que usar:

> git merge origin/master

A partir de esto tu tienes los nuevos cambios en tu rama `master` y listo.

Aquí una imagen que hice para explicar esta parte:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al usar `git pull` estas combinando `git fetch`+ `git merge`.

> git pull origin master

En conclusión con `git pull` te estás ahorrando el usar un comando más, pero te recomiendo que si apenas estás empezando a usar git, sigas usando `git fetch` y `git merge`

Answer (score 12):

En realidad `git pull` baja los cambios de la rama determinada y la actualiza contra tu repositorio local.

`git fetch` baja los cambios de la rama determinada y la coloca en una rama *espejo* que simplemente es una clase de rama *escondida* en la cual tú puedes mirar los cambios de dicha rama, para posteriormente hacer *merge* con tu rama local.

El `git pull` simplemente es un `git fecth + git merge`. No utilizar el `git pull` si en realidad está dudoso de qué cambios puedan traerse del repositorio remoto.

Comment: Tambien con ```git pull --no-commit``` se puede hacer el merge sin commit

Answer (score 4):

Cuando haces un `git fetch`, se van a descargar los cambios de tu repositorio remoto(en el caso de que haya) en una carpeta que se llama **origin/master**, que es una carpeta oculta. Para incluir los cambios a tu rama local necesitas fusionar master con origin/master.

`Git pull` hace todo eso automaticamente.

Answer (score 0):

Muy resumido: con **fetch** solo consultas los cambios que hay en el repositorio con respecto a tu copia local; y con **pull** te bajas los cambios a tu local. Creo que Sourcetree al hacer pull, hace antes un fetch también.