# Sincronizar 2 servidores GIT --bare

Tags: git

Tengo un servidor Git (en GitLab), al que solo tengo acceso de escritura a la *branch* `devel`. Por diversos motivos, tengo otro servidor Git en una máquina distinta (`myserver`). Este último se creó mediante la orden

```
git clone --bare https://GITLAB.URL/PATH/TO/REPO
```

y puedo acceder a él mediante la URL `ssh://MISERVER/PATH/TO/REPO`.

En mi máquina local, cloné desde `myserver`:

```
git clone ssh://myserver/repo.git
```

Desde ese momento, uso **exclusivamente** el repo en `myserver`: `push`, `pull`, ... todo ello sin problemas, y **siempre** en la *branch* `devel`.

Ahora, tengo que sincronizar **ambos** *repos*. Para ello, entro por `ssh` a `myserver`, y, con el usuario adecuado, intento:

> ```
>    git fetch -v origin devel
> ```
>
> Username for 'https://gitlab.com': ****
>   Password for 'https://username@gitlab.com': ****
>   From https://gitlab.com/path/to/repo
>    * branch            devel      -> FETCH_HEAD

No se muestra ningún error. A continuación, hago:

> ```
>    git push -v origin devel
> ```
>
> Pushing to https://gitlab.com/path/to/repo.git
>   Username for 'https://gitlab.com': ****
>   Password for 'https://username@gitlab.com': ****
>   To https://gitlab.com/path/to/repo.git
>
> ## ! [rejected]        devel -> devel (non-fast-forward)
>
> error: failed to push some refs to 'https://gitlab.com/path/to/repo.git'
>   hint: Updates were rejected because a pushed branch tip is behind its remote
>   hint: counterpart. Check out this branch and integrate the remote changes
>   hint: (e.g. 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
>   hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.

#### En resumen:

- repo1: maquina en gitlab (`--bare`).
- repo2: maquina en myserver (`--bare`).
- repo3: mi equipo de desarrollo (máquina local, `git clone` normal, **no** `--bare`).

Flujo de trabajo normal:

> repo3 -> pull from repo2, push to repo2.

Flujo de trabajo ocasional, objetivo de la pregunta:

> repo2 -> pull from repo1, push to repo1.

El *repo2* se creó usando `git clone --bare`. Es decir, **no tiene copia de trabajo** y **no puedo ejecutar `git pull`** en él.

En el *repo2*, el `git fetch` se ejecuta aparentemente sin errores. Sin embargo, el commando `git push` **si** muestra errores y no se realiza.

- ¿ Que estoy haciendo mal ?
- ¿ Cómo lo soluciono ?

Comment: puedes aclarar lo de los servidores? me da a entender que lo que tienes son repositorios clonados, no "servidores" como tal... El error te dice que estas intentando subir algo, cuando en el servidor remoto hay mas cosas y no has integrado esos cambios. Quizas lo que quieres es un `git pull origin devel`?

Comment: @Jakala Son 2 *repos*, cada uno en una máquina física distinta. En `myserver` se hizo un `git clone --bare`. Es decir, no tiene copia de trabajo y no puedo ejecutar `git pull` en él. Sin embargo, el `git fetch` se ejecuta **aparentemente** sin errores O_o

Answer (score 1):

Entiendo que hablamos de 3 repos (dices 2, pero nombras 3)

- Original en gitlab - rama devel (1)
- Clonado en modo bare (2)
- Local normal obtenido desde (3)

De todos modos, entiendo que:

Al hacer `git fetch -v origin devel` en (2) estás trayendo a local las copias de las ramas, pero no estás actualizando el estado de las mismas, sino [únicamente trayendo una copia local de los metadatos de las ramas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/245/cu%C3%A1l-es-la-diferencia-entre-pull-y-fetch-en-git).  OJO porque en este caso, parece que traes a (2) el estado de (1).  Cuando dices `tengo que sincronizar ambos repos` te refieres a ¿1 y 2? a ¿2 y 3?

Como dicen en el link que te he pegado,

> git pull es una abreviación de git fetch seguido de git merge FETCH_HEAD

De todos modos, he tratado de escribir la respuesta más cercana a lo que yo intentaría.

Así, entiendo que deberías hacer desde el repo (2) `git fetch origin devel:devel` para poder traer la última versión del repo (1) a (2).

De todos modos, también puedes traer al repositorio local la copia a una rama diferente y realizar el mergeo.

```
git checkout --track -b devel_copy origin/devel //Te traes la rama origen a devel_copy
git checkout devel_copy  //Asegúrate que estas en la rama local copiada
git merge devel //mergeas tus cambios que tenías en la rama local devel
git push origin devel_copy //subes tus cambios a la rama origin/devel
git fetch origin devel //traes el estado (metadata) de la rama devel de nuevo
git checkout devel //cambias a ella
git reset --hard //La reseteas para que quede asociada con el HEAD actualizado.
```

Espero que te ayude. De todos modos, decirte que también puedes revisar qué cambios contiene cada rama con `git log branchname` por lo que con un poco de paciencia, y quizá cambiando algo de lo que yo he explicado, puedas hacerlo.

Recuerda también que si tienes claro que todos tus cambios están ok, puedes forzar los push con  `git push origin devel_copy -f` (OJO al hacerlo)

Entiendo que al menos con esto tendrás algo más de pistas. Por favor, si finalmente tomas otra solución dinos cuál es o propón tú mismo una respuesta si así lo consideras.

Gracias!

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta. He editado un poco, a ver si aclaro algo mas la pregunta. Probaré lo que propones en cuanto me sea posible.

Comment: Ánimo...  siento si no es 100% precisa, pero más o menos creo que da una idea de cómo en alguna ocasión he lidiado con ello. Al final cada repo es un mundo, y podría ser que algo no funcionara. De todos modos, entiendo que podrás seguir a partir de ahí. Lo dicho, edita y mejora la respuesta o propón la tuya sin problema!! Gracias por responder!!!

Answer (score 1):

Para tener los tres repos sincronizados, me parece que lo más conveniente es hacerlo desde `local`, que es el único de los tres que es un repo de trabajo en lugar de uno `bare`.

Entonces, una vez sincronizados `local` y `myserver` (que entiendo que ya es así), lo que falta seria sincronizar `Gitlab` con `local`.

Desde el repo `local` y en el branch `devel`:

1. Verificar que este al día con `myserver`:

   `git status`

Muestra que no hay archivos modificados ni que haya que hacer un `pull` o un `push`.

2. Verificar que tenemos `origin` apuntando a `myserver` (seguro es así)

   `git remote -v`
3. Agregar `gitlab` como remote a `Gitlab`

   `git remote add gitlab https://GITLAB.URL/PATH/TO/REPO`
4. Verificar que ahora tenemos `origin` mirando a `myserver` y también, `gitlab` mirando a `Gitlab`.

   `git remote -v`
5. Traer la referencia de `devel` en `gitlab`.

   `git fetch gitlab devel`
6. Opcionalmente ver un preview de lo que se va a mergear.
   Esto es para ver los commits que difierente entre `local` y `Gitlab`, los commits precedidos por `<` indican commits que están en `local` y no en `Gitlab` y los que están precedidos por `>` indican commits que están en `Gitlab` y no en `local`.

   `git log -p --left-right devel...gitlab/devel`
7. Estando en `local` y en el branch `devel`, hacemos el merge de `devel` en `Gitlab`.

   `git merge gitlab/devel`
8. Si hay conflictos, arreglar los conflictos, y terminar el merge-commit.
9. Pushear la versión sincronizada a `myserver`

   `git push origin devel`
10. Pushea la versión sincronizada a `Gitlab`

    `git push gitlab devel`

En este punto los tres repos tienen lo mismo.

Yo creo que no hay necesidad pero si queres podés quitar el remote a `Gitlab` que habiamos agregado antes: `git remote remove gitlab`